# error: Target not found when trying to install MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain with Ruby Installer for windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, msys2, rubyinstaller

I encountered a lot of errors related to make and Makefile when installing gems for a Rails project while working with Ruby 2.4.10. Problem was that development tools weren't properly installed.

I also found that the MSYS2 version that comes with Ruby Installer with DevKit is somehow flawed. With some gems it could not download packages: `error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils-2.30-5-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : The requested URL returned error: 404`

I installed the newest version of [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) and re-installed Ruby 2.4.10 without MSYS2, since I'm not sure how to change default path of MSYS with Ruby Installer.

running `ridk install` with option 3 threw errors like this: `error: target not found: automake1.10`

Solution was to remove the error throwing packets from the `pacman` command.

By default, Ruby Installer 2.4.10 with DevKit uses this command:

```
pacman -S --needed --noconfirm autoconf autoconf2.13 autogen automake-wrapper automake1.10 automake1.11 automake1.12 automake1.13 automake1.14 automake1.15 automake1.6 automake1.7 automake1.8 automake1.9 diffutils file gawk grep libtool m4 make patch pkg-config sed texinfo texinfo-tex wget mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils mingw-w64-x86_64-crt-git mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs mingw-w64-x86_64-headers-git mingw-w64-x86_64-libmangle-git mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git mingw-w64-x86_64-make mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config mingw-w64-x86_64-tools-git mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git
```

To fix the problem, run:

```
ridk exec pacman -S --needed --noconfirm autoconf autoconf2.13 autogen automake-wrapper automake1.11 automake1.12 automake1.13 automake1.14 automake1.15 diffutils file gawk grep libtool m4 make patch pkg-config sed texinfo texinfo-tex wget mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils mingw-w64-x86_64-crt-git mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs mingw-w64-x86_64-headers-git mingw-w64-x86_64-libmangle-git mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git mingw-w64-x86_64-make mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config mingw-w64-x86_64-tools-git mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git
```